# Adding multiple selected date fields to a javafx datepickerskin

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I am working on a calendar application using javafx. Dates for the appointments are added to a database through the datepicker. The appointment shall be retrieved from the database and displayed inside three datepicker skins.

[image: Calendar app with one datepicker and three skins]

I want the datepicker skins to display multiple selected days, showing all appointments of the month on their respective dates/ days.

The code below achieves to display the appointments of several days inside the datepicker, but this doesn't help much, since the datepicker dropdown is closed after selection.

I have done a lot of googling but have been unable to find a way to display multiple selected days inside a javafx datepicker skin.

Can anyone point me to a solution of how to add several days to a datepicker skin or maybe a workaround or another tool that is not javafx?

Any help would be appreciated.

Below the code I already have.

This a working code for the datepicker:

```
   private void datepickerSetDate() throws ParseException {


    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateInString = "2017-05-27";
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateInString2 = "2017-05-29";
    Date date2 = formatter2.parse(dateInString2);


    Instant instant = date.toInstant();
    LocalDate localDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    Instant instant2 = date2.toInstant();
    LocalDate localDate2 = instant2.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    ObservableList<LocalDate> selectedDates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    selectedDates.addAll(localDate , localDate2);

    datePicker_1.setOnAction(event -> selectedDates.add(datePicker_1.getValue()));

    datePicker_1.setDayCellFactory(new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
        @Override
        public DateCell call(DatePicker param) {
            return new DateCell() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    boolean alreadySelected = selectedDates.contains(item);
                    setDisable(alreadySelected);
                    setStyle(alreadySelected ? "-fx-background-color: lightblue;" : "");
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it :

```
dp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle (ActionEvent event) {
            LocalDate date  = dp.getValue();
        }
    });

    Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {

        public DateCell call (final DatePicker datePicker ) {

            return new DateCell() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem (LocalDate item , boolean empty) {

                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.from(item);
                    if (day == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || day == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {

                        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue");

                    }                        

                    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

                    if (item.isEqual(today)) {
                        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");

                    }                                        

                }

            };

        }


    };

    dp.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
```

[image]